# python beautifulsoup fetch xml, rather than the html page it's in

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm using

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
xml = urllib2.urlopen('http://weatherlink.com/xml.php?user=blah&pass=blah')
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
print soup.prettify()
```

but that just grabs the html. If I curl it, I get a something like:

```
...
<title>blah</title>
<link>http://www.blah.com</link>
</image>
<suggested_pickup>15 minutes after the hour</suggested_pickup>
<dewpoint_c>16.7</dewpoint_c>
<dewpoint_f>62</dewpoint_f>
<heat_index_f>77</heat_index_f>
...
```

what can I do to make:

```
some_data {}
some_data [ 'dewpoint_c' ] = 16.7
some_data [ 'heat_index' ] = 77
```

where some_data would have the values from the xml it's supposed to get. I've also tried minidom and ElementTree, but having the same problem fetching xml first

Comment: 'but that just grabs the html',  it appears its returning xml,  you just need to parse it into a dictionary.  i would need to see more of the response to know how to parse it easily.

Comment: the .html it grabs is just a basic html page which doesn't show the xml which appears when you browse to the page in a browser. I'm able to get curl to get the xml at the same URL if it accepts a cookie, then I output it to somefile.xml and I use soup.find to get it, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing around with the headers and requesting XML?

```
headers = {
    "Accept":"application/xml;q=0.9,"
}
xml = urllib2.urlopen('http://weatherlink.com/xml.php?user=blah&pass=blah', headers=headers)
```

Perform the login in Chrome and use the Developer Tools, particularly the network viewer to see what's happening in your browser, then trying to replicate it via urllib2